# Symfony3 not working with homestead 5.4

Tags: symfony

My Symfony 3 and homestead 5.4 after modify app_dev.php by adding 
this line : `&& $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] != '192.168.10.10'`
work always in debug mode.

without this add : You are not allowed to access this file. Check...

Can you help me ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The app_dev.php kernel always runs the application in debug mode. For production environment run app.php kernel.

Comment: Hello, it's same on app.php not only in app_dev.php

Comment: You misconfigured something obviously. app.php kernel, under any circumstances does not load any dev extensions

Comment: Hello, no app.php kernel is original.